# How i can use Spannable String to append more images to a textfield and send it to another activity

Tags: android

I am using SpannableString to append images to a textfield but the problem is that only one image gets displayed. And also I want to know how to send the contents to another activity.Here is the code:

```
public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e){
    Toast.makeText(Createaccount_4.this, "single tap", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    int id=0;
    switch(id){
        case 0:
            id=R.id.imageView1;
            ImageView t=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            id=R.drawable.fw;
            SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("abc");
            EditText t1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            Drawable d = t.getDrawable();
            d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
            ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(d, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
            ss.setSpan(span, 0, 3, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            t1.append(ss);
        break;

        case 1:
            id=R.id.imageView2;
            SpannableString ss1 = new SpannableString("abc");
            ImageView v=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            Drawable d1 = v.getDrawable();
            d1.setBounds(0, 0, d1.getIntrinsicWidth(), d1.getIntrinsicHeight());
            ImageSpan span1 = new ImageSpan(d1, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
            ss1.setSpan(span1, 0, 3, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
            a.append(ss1);
```

Comment: Where in your code are you appending more than one image to a 'textfield' (did you mean an EditText? Why are you posting twice the same code?

Comment: I donot know much about spannable string can you provide a sample how to append two different imageViews to an edittext?

Comment: You don't answer my questions. So i follow you.

Comment: I do not understand what you are trying to say

Comment: I did answer your question I do not know much about spannable string and that's why I have done an error  and yes I want to append it to an edittext. I do not understand how to append multiple imageViews with the spannable string

Comment: Ok. but you said `but the problem is that only one image gets displayed.`. So then I ask you again: "Where in the code i can see that you try to display two images"? And i repeat also: "why did you post the same code twice?"

Comment: ok I made an error in understanding the code. Can you please help me?

Comment: I posted the code over here so that someone explains to me how to put more than one image in an edittext

Comment: Can you help me in this matter?